# Firefox - This Connection is Untrusted - Google

Tags: linux, firefox, centos, centos-7

I'm not sure why, yet all of the sudden I'm getting this while trying to open `www.google.com`

[image: This Connection is Untrusted]

My system:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ rpm -q firefox
firefox-38.5.0-3.el7.centos.x86_64
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ date
Thu Jan  7 11:44:37 EST 2016
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$
```

Everything was working fine yesterday, and according to `/var/log/yum.log` there was no updates to the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need more information about which certificate issuer is untrusted. Based on the recommendations in [this support thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1070864):

1. Paste `chrome://pippki/content/exceptionDialog.xul` into the URL bar and hit enter.
2. In the window that appears, type `https://www.google.com` into the Server Location field and click "Get Certificate".
3. Read the "Issued By" field, and paste a picture of that window here if you still can't figure out what's wrong.